# Question on Purchasing which involves a while and switch statement

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

The code is basically asking for the total cost of bags made for each different colour, I wanted the while loop to exit and the total printed and calculated. However I met upon a complication, It works to some extent but I want it to consistently loop until "6" is entered so it can total but it doesn't at all. I was wondering how to get it to loop the main question and exit plus total. It will loop the question, it can exit but the total is equal to a trash figure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
    int total, price, bags, colour, cost, Exit ;
    
    printf ("********************************************\n Enter 6 to exit if you desire to do so\n");
    printf ("********************************************\nEnter the colour you desire:\n 1)Black\n 2)Red\n 3)Yellow\n 4)Green\n 5)Other\n********************************************\n");
    scanf("%d", &colour);
    while (Exit!=6)
    {
        switch (colour)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Enter the number of bags you intend:  ");
                scanf("%d", &bags);
                price=400;
                cost=cost+(price*bags);
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                printf("Enter the number of bags you intend:  ");
                scanf("%d", &bags);
                price=350;
                cost=price*bags;
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                printf("Enter the number of bags you intend:  ");
                scanf("%d", &bags);
                price=120;
                cost=cost+(price*bags);
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                printf("Enter the number of bags you intend:  ");
                scanf("%d", &bags);
                price=200;
                cost=cost+(price*bags);
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {
                printf("Enter the number of bags you intend:  ");
                scanf("%d", &bags);
                price=50;
                cost=cost+(price*bags);
            }
            break;
            
        }
        printf("********************************************\n Are you complete with your purchase? If so enter 6\n");
        scanf("%d", &Exit);
    }
   
    printf("The total is %d", total=total+cost);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviour in several places. `total=total+cost` is one of them because `total` is unintialised.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize total and cost to zero first. As mentioned, your current setup causes undefined behavior. Here is a solution:

```
int total = 0, price, bags, colour, cost = 0, Exit = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you arę asking but if I understand correctly you want to to loop until 6 is entered.

1. All variables are uninitliazied so they are holding undefined values.  Initialize them after declaration to apropriate values. Your problem is with variables total and cost as they hold trash values at the start.

2  As for minor errors on case 2 you are missing cost on the right side.

3. You dont really need var total because your total cost is equal to the value hold by cost. Just print it.

Most of the issues you encounter are due to point 1.